# How to solve $\log_{4}(\sqrt{x^{4/3}})+3\log_{x}(16x)=7?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> How to solve $\log_{4}(\sqrt{x^{4/3}})+3\log_{x}(16x)=7?$

I've tried everything from brute force to doing base change but nothing works. I was wondering what was the best way in solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the logarithmic base to a natural log, ie
$$\log_{b}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)}$$
which then leads to
\begin{align}
\log_{4}(x^{2/3}) + 3 \, \log_{x}(16 \, x) &= 7 \\
\frac{\ln(x)}{3 \, \ln(2)} + \frac{3 \, \ln(16 \, x)}{\ln(x)} &= 7 \\
\frac{\ln(x)}{3 \, \ln(2)} + \frac{12 \, \ln(2) + 3 \, \ln(x)}{\ln(x)} &= 7 \\ 
\ln^{2}(x) - 12 \, \ln(2) \, \ln(x) + 36 \, \ln^{2}(2) &= 0 \\
\left(\ln(x) - 6 \, \ln(2) \right)^2 &= 0
\end{align}
for which it is obtained $\ln(x) = 6 \, \ln(2) = \ln(2^{6})$ or $x = 2^{6} = 64$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\log_{4}(\sqrt{x^{4/3}})+3\log_{x}(16x)&=7\\
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\log_{4}(x)+3\log_{x}(4^2)+3\log_{x}(x)&=7\\
\frac{2}{3}\log_{4}(x)+\frac{6}{\log_4x}+3&=7\\
(\log_4x)^2-6\log_4x+9&=0\\
\log_4x&=3\\
x&=64
\end{align}

Comment: I understand everything except on how $3log_{x}(4^2)$ became $\frac{6}{log_4x}$?

Comment: $3\log_x(4^2)=6\log_x4$. $\log_x4=\frac{\log_44}{\log_4x}=\frac{1}{\log_4x}$ by the change  of base formula.